# Bad Interpreter Error Trying to Install Packages in Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, path, package, anaconda

I'm trying to install `neo` into my Anaconda distribution using

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/neuroinf neo`

(taken from [here](https://binstar.org/neuroinf/neo)) but am getting the error:

`bash: /transform/anaconda/bin/conda: /usr/local/anaconda/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

It's not finding `/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python` because it doesn't exist. I have anaconda installed in `/transform/anaconda/`. I've edited my .bashrc file to reflect this but for some reason it's still looking in `/usr/local/` (at least in some way, note that it is correctly looking in `/transform/` for the first directory argument). What do I need to change to get it to look in `/transform/anaconda/bin/python`?

`echo $PATH` returns:

`/transform/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/transform/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/transform/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/PHShome/gcw8/bin`

(I realize it's messy, I'll clean it up when I get a minute)

I'm running CentOS and python 2.7.

Comment: Did you change any of the shebang lines yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no I have not, which ones do I need to change? Also, I feel that I should mention that I have used conda install successfully in the past without adding shebang lines

Comment: Maybe you should start with the one mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Oh wow, that was actually it. Thank you! Please write your response as an actual answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/transform/anaconda/bin/conda` expects the Python executable to be in `/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python` since that is what is in its shebang line, but you've installed it elsewhere, specifically `/transform/anaconda/bin/python`. You will need to modify the shebang line to point to the correct location.

Comment: I used the following command to replace the old path of all my shebang lines with the new path: `sed -i 's/old\/path/new\/path/g' anaconda/bin/*` (use the backslash to escape the forward slashes).

Answer (score 3):

Did you move your Anaconda installation? This is not supported, for this exact reason.

After modifying the shebang to fix Anaconda you may need to use `conda` to uninstall and reinstall any other package that has shebang lines or other hard-coded paths to fix them.